# Exact Difference between NSURLConnection and NSUrlSession?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I am new to the concept of `NSURLSession`. Now I am working on the sample on `NSURLSession`. I read so many answers about the difference between them but I didn't understand clearly.Can any one please tell me the difference between them with simple example.

Comment: you can get difference of both perfectly from this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-1--mobile-21394

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSURLConnection is a much older API, introduced in OS X 10.2.

NSURLSession was introduced in OS X 10.9, and has a more modern (task- and block-based) API. It is the successor to NSURLConnection, and you should use it in all new projects.

[This objc.io post](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession/) has more information about the two.